# How to parse emails and extract header and body part

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a email file, if I open it as a text file, I see lots of nuisance. And if I open it in a mail program such as Kmail I can see what I can say as a simplified email, with subject, from, to, date and body.

1. I want to do the same in Java. Currently I'm reading the email file straight away and thus there are lot's of nuisance (HTML, etc) along with header fields and body.
2. Further I also want to check if a message is Base64 encoded or not!

Please guide me for these two things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this MimeMessage constructor](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage%28javax.mail.Session,%20java.io.InputStream%29).  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) for the other things you'll need to know.

Comment: Thanks for this! I found that mime4j is better than JavaMail as JavaMail fails to parse some of the mime messages!

Comment: For example?  Did you find all the properties you can set to make JavaMail more tolerant of incorrectly formatted messages?

Comment: Well till now I had no problems with JavaMail API! It is simple and intuitive. So I am accepting your answer :)!